# Error extracting data using TPT script for Fixed width table

Tags: sql, teradata, fixed-width

I am trying to export data from a fixed width table ( teradata)

**The following is the error log**

```
 Found CheckPoint file: /path
 This is a restart job; it restarts at step MAIN_STEP.
 Teradata Parallel Transporter DataConnector Version 13.10.00.05
 FILE_WRITER Instance 1 directing private log report to 'dataconnector_log-1'.
 Teradata Parallel Transporter SQL Selector Operator Version 13.10.00.05
 SQL_SELECTOR: private log specified: selector_log
 FILE_WRITER: TPT19007 DataConnector Consumer operator Instances: 1
 FILE_WRITER: TPT19003 ECI operator ID: FILE_WRITER-31608
 FILE_WRITER: TPT19222 Operator instance 1 processing file 'path/out.dat'.
 SQL_SELECTOR: connecting sessions
 SQL_SELECTOR: TPT15105: Error 13 in finalizing the table schema definition
 SQL_SELECTOR: disconnecting sessions
 SQL_SELECTOR: Total processor time used = '0.02 Second(s)'
 SQL_SELECTOR: Start : Sat Aug  9 12:37:48 2014
 SQL_SELECTOR: End   : Sat Aug  9 12:37:48 2014
 FILE_WRITER: TPT19221 Total files processed: 0.
 Job step MAIN_STEP terminated (status 12)
 Job edwaegcp terminated (status 12)
```

**TPT script used :**

```
 USING CHARACTER SET UTF8
 DEFINE JOB EXPORT_DELIMITED_FILE
 DESCRIPTION 'Export rows from a Teradata table to a  file'

(



    DEFINE SCHEMA PRODUCT_SOURCE_SCHEMA
    (
    id char(20)
    );
    DEFINE OPERATOR SQL_SELECTOR
    TYPE SELECTOR
    SCHEMA PRODUCT_SOURCE_SCHEMA
    ATTRIBUTES
    (
            VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'selector_log',
                    VARCHAR TdpId= '****',
                    VARCHAR UserName= '****',
                    VARCHAR UserPassword='*****',
                    VARCHAR SelectStmt= 'LOCKING ROW FOR ACCESS SELECT 
                    CAST(id AS CHAR(20)),
                    FROM sample_db.sample_table'
   );
    DEFINE OPERATOR FILE_WRITER
    TYPE DATACONNECTOR CONSUMER
    SCHEMA *
    ATTRIBUTES
    (
                    VARCHAR PrivateLogName = 'dataconnector_log',
                    VARCHAR DirectoryPath  = '/path/',
                    VARCHAR Format = 'Text',
                    VARCHAR FileName= 'out.dat',
                    VARCHAR OpenMode= 'Write'

    );
    APPLY TO OPERATOR (FILE_WRITER)

    SELECT * FROM OPERATOR (SQL_SELECTOR);
    );
```

Could you point out the error in the TPT script thats leading to this error?

or

How do we extract a fixed width table using TPT?

Comment: It appears there is an unmatched closing paren with a  semicolon at the end of your script. I've looked over your script a couple times and it seems you may have not included opening paren after `DEFINE SCHEMA PRODUCT_SOURCE_SCHEMA`.